# Firebird database - isql command not found

Tags: docker, debian, firebird

I have a problem with the firebird database. When I use `docker run -it jacobalberty / firebird bash` my isql command works but when i run `docker exec -it firebird bash` my isql command no longer works and i get the error `bash: isql: command not found`.

Comment: Docker run starts the specified image, while docker exec attaches to the specified container. So, what is the container `firebird`? Which image is it running?

Comment: However, at a guess, the `/usr/local/firebird/bin/firebird` location is only added to the PATH when starting the image. When you attach and launch bash to a running container, that location isn't on the PATH.